# PHP login sessions errors.not entering the destination age even if the crediantials are correct

Tags: php, html

I'm not able to move from the login page even if the login is successful, even if the credentials are correct the same page stays on but dosent go to the index page.

In the below code if the credentials are correct it should direct to the index page, but the page stays in the login page.
But if i host this same code in wamp it working but when it comes to linux I am facing this issue.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<a href="view.php">
<img src="logo.png" style="vertical-align:bottom; padding: 2px;">
</a>
<section id="content">
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['url'])) 
$url = $_SESSION['url']; // holds url for last page visited.
else 
$url = "index.php";  //home page 
// include mylib.php (contains Logging class)
include('mylib.php');
// Logging class initialization
$log = new Logging();
// set path and name of log file (optional)
$log->lfile('user_logins.log');
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
$adServer = "ldap://ldap.com";
$ldap = ldap_connect($adServer);
$username = $_POST['username']; 
$password = $_POST['password'];
#$_SESSION['user'] = $username;
$ldaprdn = 'm' . "\\" . $username;
#$ldaprdn = $username;
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
$bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $ldaprdn, $password);
$real_name="";
$groupToAllow = "CN=***,OU=***DC=test,DC=com";
$baseDn="CN=***,OU=***DC=test,DC=com";
$_SESSION['admin']= false;
if ($bind) {
$log->lwrite("$username authenticated sucessfully..");
$filter="(sAMAccountName=$username)";
$result = ldap_search($ldap,$baseDn,$filter);
ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"sn");
$info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
$authorized= fale;
for ($i=0; $i<$info[0]["memberof"]["count"]; $i++) 
{                   
if ( strtoupper($info[0]["memberof"][$i]) == strtoupper($groupToAllow))
{   
$log->lwrite("$username belongs to the group $groupToAllow");               
$log->lwrite("$username is an authorised user");                
$_SESSION['user']=$info[0]["givenname"][0];
$_SESSION['email'] = $info[0]["userprincipalname"][0];
$_SESSION['admin'] = true;
$authorized= true;
break;
}
}
if ($authorized === true) {
$userDn = $info[0]["distinguishedname"][0];                         
// write message to the log file
$log->lwrite("$userDn logged in sucessfully..");
header("Location: $url");
} else {
$log->lwrite("Error: $username doesn't belongs to the group "); 
$log->lwrite("Error: $username is not authorised to login");
header("Location: Not_authorised.php");
}
@ldap_close($ldap);
} else {
$log->lwrite($_POST['username'] ." tried to login, but failed..");
header("Location: loginerror.php");
}
}else{
?>
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
<h1>Login Form</h1>
<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" id="username"  name="username"/>
</div>
<div>
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" name="password"/>
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form><!-- form -->
<?php } ?> 
</section><!-- content -->
</div><!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you have printed something , you are block the next header function.

You should perform all checks before printing html .

Remember , PHP is a scripting language and runs from top to bottom of the document. When you print something in html and then open the php tags , document headers are different and you can not do a URL redirect.

```
<html>
<head>
  .... --> this not working .
</head>
<body>
<?php 

     if(!empty($_SESSION['login'])&&){
       //all your code implementation

       //now you can call your template file
       include 'account.php';

     }else{

       //return to index or the login page
       header('location:index.php');
     }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

The solution is checked all step on top with PHP.

```
<?php 

     if(!empty($_SESSION['login'])&&){
       //all your code implementation

       //now you can call your template file
       //include 'account.php';

       //OR print html
     ?>
        <html>
           <head>
           </head>
           <body>
                Hi user : <?=$user?>
           </body>
        </html>
     <?php

     }else{

       //return to index or the login page
       header('location:index.php');
     }

?>
```

Also, I advise that you should separate your PHP code HTML code. A good tool can be Smarty .

Whit Smarty you can checked all that you want and declare vars for the template.

Also do loops or structures of Control ont template.

I hope I've helped
Good luck!!

Comment: what is accounts.php in this case ?

Comment: I have seperated the html and the php codes but when i host in windows its working but when i host in linux its not directing to index.php even though it successfull.Can you please help on this.Thank you

Comment: I have found out the issue,the session pages are not working in linux which are working in linux.BUt no solution found on this.